# Where is the reference to the .m file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I created a new Xcode project (iOS application, Tabbed Application).

Now I'm seeing one sample code that Xcode generated for me (that I did not touch at all) and of course, it works on the iPhone simulator.

I am going through the code and though I'm seeing references to the .h files, I do not see any reference in any of the created files to .m files. (as in

```
#import "MRTAppDelegate.h"

#import "MRTFirstViewController.h"

#import "MRTSecondViewController.h"
```

Does the compiler just process whatever .m files you add to the project? Is there a list where they are all accounted for?

p.s. As it is obvious I also have little Objective C background, whatever I could carry from my university C classes.

Comment: It just like in C when you import a header. The linker will link all the `.m` files that are compiled by your compiler together.

Comment: In Xcode's case, does this mean, all the .m's I put on the left-hand pane?

Comment: Not exactly. It's all the .m files that are in your compilation unit. To view your compilation unit, you can select your project, then navigate to build-phases->compile sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you go to build phrases -> compiled sources all the .m as specified there.

Answer (score 0):

You're right on the basic assumption that Xcode will link the header and implementation for you. Just make sure you're added the .m file to your build sources and Xcode will do the rest.

You're also always going to #import the header file, and not the implementation file, in other classes.

Comment: Thanks. This leads me another question I had in mind. May I have the .m and .h files with different names before the dot? (I know it wouldn't make sense but anyhow). Am I safe, having imported `abc.h` in `def.m` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Has been a long time since I was a newbie for something. I think I might be getting lost in details but what to do.